# Dependency injection for generic interface with some parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, dependency-injection

I want to give parameters when injecting generic types. Is this possible?

My generic type definition:

```
public interface IApiClient<T> where T : class
{
    
}

public class ApiClient<T> : IApiClient<T> where T : class
{
    public ApiClient(string baseAddress = "", string endpoint = "")
    {
        //some codes
    }
}
```

My implementation is:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IApiClient<>), typeof(ApiClient<>));
```

How do I give `baseAddress` and `endpoint` in this usage?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to give us more info. Are we supposed to read your mind to figure out what `services.AddSingleton` is?

Comment: Those seems like good candidates of being controlled via `IOptions` so they can be sourced from configuration values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make separate class for the constructor parameters.

For example based on your code:

```
public class ApiClientSettings 
{
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
}
```

Create an instance of the `ApiClientSettings` (or even you can simply get values from `appsettings.json` file). Then register `ApiClientSettings` in the container.

```
var apiClientSettings = new ApiClientSettings
{
    BaseAddress = "address",
    Endpoint = "endpoint"
};
services.AddSingleton(apiClientSettings);
```

Inject settings class to your `ApiClient`

```
public class ApiClient<T> : IApiClient<T> where T : class
{
    public ApiClient(ApiClientSettings settings)
    {
        //some codes
    }
}
```